# can't get pdf file as output using php,mysql

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I want to Generate PDF file using fpdf

but i got error like :
fpdf error: some data has already been output cannot be send pdf file

```
<?php
    $indexcontent = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['index']);
     $detailview = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `searchengine` WHERE `indexcontent` = '$indexcontent'") or die(mysql_error());
    if($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($detailview))
    {
    $filepdf = $result['maincontent'];
    require('fpdf.php');
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'$filepdf');
    $pdf->Output();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not put vars between single quotes, try to put between double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<?php
    $indexcontent = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['index']);
    $detailview = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `searchengine` WHERE `indexcontent` = '$indexcontent'") or die(mysql_error());
    require('fpdf.php');
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    if($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($detailview))
    {
    $filepdf = $result['maincontent'];

    $pdf->Cell(40,10,$filepdf);

    }
    $pdf->Output();

?>
```

Comment: Instead of '$filepdf' write just $filepdf

Comment: i have a content with html tags in $result['maincontent'] . now it prints result like <p>some text</p><div>some content</div>.I would like to print result as normal html view.

Comment: that you have to parse the content before assigning it to the $filepdf variable